# How to measure micro and nano amps via microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, current-measurement

The objective is to build/construct a circuit powered by an ATMEGA32 IC, using C++. This circuit will essentially be an ammeter for small current levels (10<sup>-6</sup> and 10<sup>-9</sup>).

I've done some basic points from reading the forums:

- Assign on or the ports of the IC to the purpose of being an ammeter
- Possible current control via a hall effect sensor and MOSFET
- Op-Amp used for the voltage regulation as an alternative without the need to develop a control system PID for it.
- The output will ideally go to an LCD screen displaying current measurement as it is connected with a circuit.

Any pointers that can help me on my way?

Many thanks

Comment: [https://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/](https://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a [transimpedance amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier), which will give you zero burden (negligible voltage drop). You have to use an amplifier with very low bias current compared to your measured current to get good accuracy. For example, an amplifier with 1pA bias current and a 10M feedback resistor would give you an accurate 1V out for -100nA in. You can feed that into the ADC and display it. As this (ignore the photodiode).

[image]

You can switch Rf to different values for different ranges (eg. 3nA/30nA/300nA/3uA full scale would require 1G/100M/10M/1M resistors).

Making circuits to measure nA accurately (pA or fA leakage) requires care. Google electrometer circuits for more details, there is more to it than is appropriate for this answer format.